# While keeping mouse-over in some content, replace the content

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseover

While hover the content is changed, but the old content is not replaced while i am removing the hover.

```js
$('div.animalcontent').hide();
$('div').hide();
$('p.animal').bind('mouseover', function() {
  $('p.animal').hide();
  $('div.animalcontent').fadeOut();
  $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'content').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.animalcontent {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='animal' id='dog'>dog url</p>
<div id='dogcontent' class='animalcontent'>Doggiecontent!</div>
```

Anyone know the way?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NeaWm/914/
Check this fiddle link

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, jQuery 1.5.2 is over 7 years out of date. You should upgrade it immediately, ideally to something on the v3 branch.

Your issue is because you have no logic governing the `mouseleave` event to replace the state of the content you've faded in/out.

That being said, you don't need JS for this at all as CSS is far more appropriate for this task as it removes the reliance on JS (which may be disabled) and it also performs much better.

You can use the `:hover` pseudo selector along with the `transition` rule to perform the fading. Something like this:

```css
.hover-toggle-container { 
  position: relative;
  height: 1.5em;
}
.hover-toggle-container > div {
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.3s; 
}

.hover-toggle-container .primary { opacity: 1; }
.hover-toggle-container .secondary { opacity: 0; }

.hover-toggle-container:hover .primary { opacity: 0; }
.hover-toggle-container:hover .secondary { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="hover-toggle-container">
  <div class="primary">dog url</div>
  <div class="secondary">Doggiecontent!</div>
</div>

<div class="hover-toggle-container">
  <div class="primary">Foo</div>
  <div class="secondary">Bar</div>
</div>
```

Note that this logic is also DRY and can be used for multiple `.hover-toggle-container` elements, as can be seen in the demo above.